# Compare indices of arrays

Tags: python

I have three arrays, and my goal is to compare the indices and choose the max number in each case. For example:

```
    a = [1,5,3,2,1]
    b = [34,1,5,4,7]
    c = [5,2,4,12,2]
```

I also have four variables to hold the counts

```
    a_count = 0
    b_count = 0
    c_count = 0
    no_count = 0
```

If the max number for index 0 is found in a, then a_count += 1, same goes to b and c, and b_count and c_count respectively. But if in any case the number at a particular index is similar, no_count += 1.

I have experience collecting max of each index in a list using zip, but this is somehow different, and I don't even know how to get started with it.

Comment: `the number at a particular index is similar`, please be more specific, what do you mean with similar?

Comment: if a[i] == b[i] or a[i] == c[i] then no_count  += 1

Comment: @PM77-1 I already edited the post. Was initially working with 2d array so I flattened it to 1d. Please refresh.

Answer (score 0):

There's better ways to do this, but this works and is quite readable.

```
a = [1,5,3,2,1]
b = [34,1,5,4,7]
c = [5,2,4,12,2]
a_count = 0
b_count = 0
c_count = 0
no_count = 0

for A,B,C in zip(a,b,c): # Take one element from each list at a time.
    D = max(A,B,C)
    if   A == B == D: no_count += 1
    elif A == C == D: no_count += 1
    elif B == C == D: no_count += 1
    elif A == D: a_count += 1
    elif B == D: b_count += 1
    elif C == D: c_count += 1
```

Comment: This is giving b_count = 5 and the rest 0. which is not the case.

Comment: Changed it. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
    a = [2,4,2,1,4]
    b = [1,2,4,2,5]
    c = [5,1,1,3,9]

    a_count = 0
    b_count = 0
    c_count = 0
    no_count = 0

    def function(list1,list2, list3): #def returns 3rd list 
        max_list = [max(value) for value in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
        return max_list

    bob = function(a,b,c)

    for i in range(len(bob)):
        if bob[i] == a[i]:
            a_count += 1
        elif bob[i] == b[i]:
            b_count += 1
        elif bob[i] == c[i]:
            c_count += 1
        else:
            no_count += 1
```

Was able to have it work using this naive way

Comment: can you compare the output of your code with mine for the *same* input arrays? It can be written in less lines.

Comment: Thanks @panadestein your code also works well and more cool. Will try to understand how it works.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add more details about the implementation. Happy to help if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your question, this might be what you are looking for:

```
a = [1, 5, 3, 2, 1]
b = [34, 1, 5, 4, 7]
c = [5, 2, 4, 12, 2]

# Create placeholder list

vals = [0, 0, 0, 0]

# Loop through the triplets of elements a[i], b[i], c[i]

for elem in zip(a, b, c):
    if len(elem) != len(set(elem)):
        vals[3] += 1
    else:
        vals[elem.index(max(elem))] += 1

a_count, b_count, c_count, no_count = vals
print(a_count, b_count, c_count, no_count)
# 1 3 1 0
```

Some comments about the implementation. First, we create for convenience a placeholder list `vars` whose elements correspond to the values of `a_count, b_count, c_count, no_count` respectively. Then we loop through the triplets of values `a[i], b[i], c[i]` (this is done with the zip function in the for loop). In this loop, first we test if length of the triplet is equal to the length of a set of the triplet elements (since sets can only have unique elements, this ensures that there are no repetitions), if this condition doesn't hold, then we increase the corresponding values of `a_count, b_count, c_count`.